# If there are two different ways to solve the OP's problem, should I post two answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Let's say the OP asks a question, and I see that it can be solved 2 different ways. (For example, a search and replace, or a macro) Should I post two separate answers or one answer describing both ways?

If I post two answers, that allows each answer to be voted on individually, so the better answer will rise to the top. But, posting multiple answers always feels a little weird, and it might be seen as rep-whoring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

I think OP will have a preference, but another person may have another preference. And having different answers will emphasis the "answer" aspect instead of the "answerer" aspect.

I am pretty sure there is nearly always different ways to achieve the same thing, and posting the whole range of possibility may interest more person and give more insights.

e.g. this question: [Add constant integer to visually selected numbers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/add-constant-integer-to-visually-selected-numbers)

There are (at the time of writing) 3 distincts methods:

- Visual-Block Increment
- Substitution
- Macro

Each are perfectly valid answers, but use a different aspect of Vim. I personally prefer substitution, but you may prefer macro, so having both answer will enhance our understanding. The OP will still accept the answer that suits him, but all answers may help.

Also I think the "rep-whoring" point should not be as important as you think. If you came with two different valid solutions, then you can earn two upvotes. I don't see any problem in that.